# Dispaly div as sidebar only on mobile device only using bootstrap

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

i would like act a div as overlay sidebar only on mobile device. Other than mobile device it should act as normal div.

Sample Code:

```
<div class="row">
   <div class="col-lg-3" id="sidebar">
     overlay sidebar only on mobile device
   </div>
   <div class="col-lg-9 col-12">
   </div>
</div>
```

how do i make `id="sidebar"` act as normal div and sidebar on mobile device.

Comment: You can achieve using media query

Comment: @JustCode how can i do that, i want it as div in lager screen and tablet and act as sidebar nav in mobile device

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/rakeshnayak/ez93bfdm/3/ is this what you are looking for?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can achieve using media query

```
@media screen and (max-width:767px){ //targets the mobile devices
 #sidebar{
   /*css code goes here*/
 }
}
```

Comment: can you make a simple example. sidebar means navigation,

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/rakeshnayak/ez93bfdm/3/ is this what you are looking for?

Comment: try @media screen and (max-device-width:767px)

Answer (score 0):

The best way would be to use jquery to collapse its width when the size for mobile screens has been attained

Answer (score 0):

You should use d-block or d-none property like this:

```
d-sm-none or d-sm-block
```